# How to previewing GitHub style markdown in PHPStorm

Tags: github, markdown, phpstorm

PHPStorm has a markdown previewer but it doesn't interpret things in the same way that GitHub does.  I'd really like to see a GitHub style preview instead of the standard markdown.  I found https://github.com/nicoulaj/idea-markdown which indicates it adds markdown support, but I'm specifically looking for GitHub flavored markdown.

Answer (score 13):

The [gfm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7701?pr=clion) plugin does that, and works with PhpStorm 9's latest EAP. It actually previews GitHub flavoured markdown, but I don't think it would be a problem for most.

It integrates as a tab at the bottom of markdown documents. Splitting the window and enabling the editor in one pane and the preview in the other worked just fine.

[image: gfm markdown preview in phpstorm 9]

Comment: That seems more functional than my answer. +1

Comment: I downloaded that plugin, but can't get the darned thing to work.  Seems it doesn't provide a file type, or any kind of file association.

Comment: Note that markdown support, as a language, is afaik not bundled on PhpStorm. You may have to install it (search for Markdown support in the list of Jetbrains repositories (currently at version 8.0.0.20150619). As far as I am concerned, the gfm plugin only shows up as an extra tab at the bottom of markdown documents.

Comment: This plugin causes PhpStorm 2019.3 to crash immediately. Doesn't seem like the repo is maintained any more.

Answer (score 4):

You can check out this [Markdown previewer](http://parsedown.org/demo), based on the work of  [Emanuil Rusev (`erusev`)](https://github.com/erusev) and [his repo on GitHub](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown). Preview: [**caret.io**](http://caret.io/).

It seems to support most of the GitHub Flavored markdown (not not the table, though):

[image: preview]

[Emanuil Rusev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200145/emanuil-rusev) (creator of [Markdown previewer](http://parsedown.org/demo)) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560453/how-to-previewing-github-style-markdown-in-phpstorm/22575534?noredirect=1#comment50115683_22575534):

> Parsedown does support tables.

Comment: @simPod I have replaced that link by a new one.

Comment: Author of Parsedown here. Thanks for the mention. This might be a bit irrelevant, but we're working on a Markdown editor for the Desktop - both Mac and Win. It has great support for Markdown and GFM. I could post a link to a "teaser" website sometime this week.

Comment: Oh, and Parsedown does support tables.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev Looks great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: As I promised, here's the teaser website for the Markdown editor that we're working on: http://caret.io